# Iterating over all previous values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column `Profile ID` . I want to compare this `profile ID` with all other previous Profile Ids and see whether it is new or duplicate

Eg i have two columns:

```
Profile ID  Duploicate/Unique
1             Unique
1             Duplicate
2             Unique
3             Unique
2             Duplicate
```

I want result like this comapre each value with each previous value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df['Duplicate/Unique1'] = np.where(df['Profile ID'].duplicated(),'Duplicate','Unique')
print (df)
   Profile ID Duplicate/Unique Duplicate/Unique1
0           1           Unique            Unique
1           1        Duplicate         Duplicate
2           2           Unique            Unique
3           3           Unique            Unique
4           2        Duplicate         Duplicate
```